how to test localhost API from docker container
I am  a little new to docker and I trying to figure out how to use docker compose. So far I have only created a test API called "http://localhost:3000/test" which would just return a "Hello World". If i run my device using node index.js, the url would work completely find. However, the url would not work if I run using docker compose.
Here are the detailed code:
index.js:
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).send('Hello World');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

backend.dockerfile:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install && npm install -g nodemon

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server/index.js"]

compose.yaml:
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4000:4000

After running *docker compose build * and docker compose up:
docker compose up
time="2024-07-25T21:05:29-05:00" level=warning msg="C:\\Users\\...\\...\\...\\compose.yaml: `version` is obsolete"
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container backend  Recreated                                                                                                                              0.1s 
Attaching to backend
backend  | Server running on port 4000


3000 or 4000? You use both.

You would connect to your service running in Docker at http://localhost:4000/test

EXPOSE probably doesn't do what you think it does. See What is the difference between "expose" and "publish" in Docker?
